# Pipe symbol | in AWK field delimiter

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file `foo` that has the following data:

```
A<|>B<|>C<|>D
1<|>2<|>3<|>4
```

I want to properly access each column using awk, but it isn't properly interpreting the field separator.

When I run:

```
head foo | \
  awk 'BEGIN {FS="<|>"} {out=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){out=out" "$i}; print out}'
```

instead of printing

```
A B C D
1 2 3 4
```

it prints

```
A | B | C | D 
1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

What's the reason behind this?

Comment: Just a hint: Instead of `head foo` you can use `NR<11` in `awk`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pipe is a special character in a regex, so you need to escape it with a backslash. But this backslash is also a special character for the string literal, so it needs to be escaped again. So you end up with the following:

```
awk -F '<\\|>' '{$1=$1}1'

awk 'BEGIN {FS="<\\|>"} {$1=$1}1'
```

The reason for this syntax is explained quite well here: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps. In short, the expression is parsed twice.

Comment: @EdMorton Are you referring to the original revision, or the edit by hek2mgl? To be honest I only posted the answer after three people asked me to (see comments on the other answer), but I can't delete it because it is  accepted.

Comment: Made an edit to clarify this a bit. Interesting question though in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

Awk reads your separator as a regex, "`<` or `>`". You have to escape the pipe character (twice, seeing that dynamic regexps such as the field separator are [scanned twice](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps)): `"<\\|>"`.

You can specify the field separator also as a parameter:

```
awk -F '<\\|>' '{out=""; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){out=out" "$i}; print out}' <<< 'A<|>B<|>C<|>D'
 A B C D
```

Depending on your version of awk, you might get away with just single escaping. For me, mawk 1.3.3 works with both `-F '<\|>'` and `-F '<\\|>'`, and gawk 4.0.1 requires `-F '<\\|>'`. I'm not fully sure which way [POSIX awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) goes, but running gawk in `--posix` mode requires the double escapes, too.

Comment: Could be written like this: `awk 'BEGIN {FS="<\\|>"} {$1=$1}1'` or even `awk -F '<\|>' '{$1=$1}1'`

Comment: @user000001 Why not putting the latter one into an answer? Also wanted to answer that :) But it should be  `awk -F'<\\|>' '$1=$1'`

Comment: I've tried this originally. dereferencing the | doesn't work properly. It says the following

awk: warning: escape sequence `\|' treated as plain `|' which I don't quite understand

Comment: @hek2mgl No that will not print lines where the first field is zero

Comment: @user000001 Adding it as your own answer would better reflect my (non-)skills in awk.

Comment: @user000001 Fair point. But still you need `-F'<\\|>'` instead of `-F'<\|>'`

Comment: @Andrew The reason is that the backslash `\\` is a special character for both the string literal, and the regular expression. So you need to double escape it.

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes, my answer was copy-pasted from my console. I use mawk 1.3.3.

Comment: @Andrew Don't worry about rep. The point is to get the questions answered. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Btw, also `sed` can be used here:

```
sed 's/<|>/ /g' file
```

If you want to "include" the `head` command:

```
sed -n '1,10s/<|>/ /gp' file
```