# Unix Shell Script - AWK delimiter issue

Tags: awk

I have following lines in a file. Please note I have intentionally kept the extra hash between 2 and 0 in the 2nd line.
File name : test.txt

```
Name#|#Age#|#Dept  
AC#|#2#0#|#Science  
BC#|#22#|#Commerce
```

I am using awk to get the data in Dept column

```
awk -F "#|#" -v c="Dept" 'NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==c){p=i; break}; next} {print $p}' "test.txt" >> result.txt
```

The result.txt shows me the following

```
|  
Commerce
```

The first line is coming as pipe because if the extra # in the first line.
Can anyone help on this

Comment: Maybe try `awk -F "#[|]#"`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pipe symbol | in AWK field delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801373/pipe-symbol-in-awk-field-delimiter)

Comment: `awk -F'#\|#'` will work too.

Comment: @karakfa: I get the same result as the OP with that one, but using `#\\|#` seems to work... (awk --version 20070501)

Comment: yes, it might be `awk` specific.  `mawk` is fine with one backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the meaning of the delimiter set is: `match # or #`. The pipe `|` character in this case acts as an `OR` statement; instead try using:

```
awk -F '#[|]#' ...
```

Putting `|` into a character class `[ ... ]` `awk` will match it literally.

Answer (score 0):

If you desire to extract Dept in your content, here's a good choice you can choose from,

```
 awk -F'#' 'NR>1{print $NF}' test.txt
```

output:

```
Science  
Commerce
```