# Escaping regex in a Ruby awk system command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, awk

The following works directly in my Mac OS X terminal, creating a file with a few lines:

```
awk '!/^1499\||^1598\||^1599\||^1999\||^2298\||^2299\||^2403\|/' "#{working_path}" > "#{filtered_file_path}"
```

However, when I attempt to use it in Ruby on Rails using backticks, the resulting file is empty:

```
`awk '!/^1499\||^1598\||^1599\||^1999\||^2298\||^2299\||^2403\|/' "#{working_path}" > "#{filtered_file_path}"`
```

An awk with a simple regex works. For example:

```
`awk '!/SMITH/' "#{working_path}" > "#{filtered_file_path}"`
```

So, the issue appears to be with the escaped pipe characters.

Ideas?

---

Some background I should have provided:

The file I am processing is pipe-delimited. I am filtering out lines with certain codes that are in the first value on the line. So, the regex I am using is something like `^2298\|`.

The other pipes in the expression in single quotes are regex OR operators.

"working_path" and "filtered_file_path" are Ruby variables.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/^1499\|^1598\|^1599\|^...` ? I'm kind of suprized this works from the cmd line. Regex "OR" is done with one `|` char. Boolean logic is done with two (`||`). What happens if you just use `|` ? Good luck.

Comment: Why not just do the filtering natively in ruby?

Comment: @shelter Good question. I could have provided more detail. The file I am working on is a pipe-delimited file, so I am searching for certain codes in the first column (e.g. 1499|). The backslash escapes the literal pipe character, and the next pipe character is the OR operator.

Comment: @TomFenech Another good question. Thanks for contributing to the conversation. 

The simple answer is speed. This is a 2.3 million line file that I have to do several operations on. In addition to the awk, I'm running sort and comm on it. Doing the operations as Linux commands gets them done an order of magnitude faster than in Ruby. I love many things about Ruby, but processing large text files can be slower than one would hope.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. The backslash that is escaping the pipe characters also needs to be escaped. Not sure why there is a difference between the regular Terminal and Ruby, but there it is. The working version:

```
`awk '!/^1499\\||^1598\\||^1599\\||^1999\\||^2298\\||^2299\\||^2403\\|/' "#{working_path}" > "#{filtered_file_path}"`
```

After challenging my assumption that the problem was Ruby on Rails, the accepted answer here is what explained it:
[Pipe symbol | in AWK field delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801373/pipe-symbol-in-awk-field-delimiter)